# tcp_connection_destination_fail net_helper_connect_fail failed (meteorjs & phonegap in iOS emmulator)

Tags: ios, cordova, ios6, meteor

I'm in the iOS emmulator (current latest versions of all software, iphone 6.0 emmulator) and I'm monitoring the syslog for my application.

I'm getting some very odd error I can't find anything about on basic searching...

```
Apr 14 22:42:31 AlanMacBook MyApp[12051]: Finished load of: http://localhost:3000/
Apr 14 22:42:31 AlanMacBook MyApp[12051]: tcp_connection_destination_fail net_helper_connect_fail failed
```

I'm wondering if this has to do with meteor's long-polling sockjs connection somehow?

I'm getting intermittent flakiness on loading of assets, etc.

Any idea what's causing the errors and if I should be concerned?